# Symfony 3.3 - where does assets:install look for web assets?

Tags: symfony, console, assets

Back in Symfony 2.x, the `assets:install` command looked for assets in `/path/to/YourProject/YourBundle/src/Resources/public` and copied (or symlinked, depending on whether or not the flag was used) those files to `/web`.  Now that assets are stored in `/path/to/YourProject/app/Resources` in Symfony 3+, does the console command look there instead?  Should I even bother using that console command at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the recent symfony best practice store your assets directly in `web` folder. Check this out: https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html

This way your assets will be available without touching server-side commands. Also any frontend developer working on your project does not need to know anything about symfony, he will work directly with assets in `web` folder and templates in `app/Resources/views`